# How do I set my foo.war's root path to be /foo/bar instead of /foo?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I have a project that compiles to foo.war. When I drop it into Tomcat, the index page is accessible at localhost:8080/foo/ with various servlets and assets as subdirectories of /foo/

What I want is to turn the /foo/ part into /foo/bar/ without having to modify every single servlet and move all of my static assets into a /bar/ folder. Is this possible?

I can control the web.xml file but not the final Tomcat server that it will be hosted on. I *think* there's a way to do this in web.xml but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible... This taken from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)  
.

"If you want to deploy a WAR file or a directory using a context path that is not related to the base file name then one of the following options must be used to prevent double-deployment:

    1.) Disable autoDeploy and deployOnStartup and define all Contexts in server.xml
    2.) Locate the WAR and/or directory outside of the Host's appBase and use a context.xml file with a docBase attribute to define it."

Both of those options require server access, correct?

Comment: Nevermind, I don't think that applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most easy (and recommended) way is to rename `foo.war` → `foo#bar.war`. That is all that needed.
[Documentation (Tomcat 7)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming)

You are not saying what version of Tomcat you use. I am assuming that it is some modern version that is not older than 3 years.

Comment: So.. it showed up in the manager application with the correct URL, but now the servlet won't actually start:
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.netflix.karyon.server.guice.KaryonGuiceContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/watson-dashboard%23ui/WEB-INF/lib/archaius-core-0.6.0.jar (No such file or directory)
        at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.JarArchive.<init>(JarArchive.java:55)